# If someone is executed under Sharia Law, are they granted heaven exclusively in the afterlife?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, jannah, punishment, hudud

If a man (or women) is punished to death for some cardinal sin dictated to such punishment under sharia law, upon his death, in his afterlife will the soul be granted heaven exclusively?  I think it should be as such since the person already punished on earth using God's Law. Else, the soul will be punished twice, isn't?

How if another person did the same cardinal sin but didn't get caught and lived all his life before died on natural causes?

How these two souls will be treated in afterlife? How Qur'an or Hadith dictates events for these situations?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. These are too many questions, consider splitting them into separate posts ([Why we should avoid asking multi-question questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions) . This appears relevant [Does punishment in the worldly life replace punishment in the hereafter?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40701/does-punishment-in-the-worldly-life-replace-punishment-in-the-hereafter)

Comment: What if they commit two sins, and are executed for only one of those sins?

Comment: @Medi1Saif  There cannot be one answer that can satisfy confusions arise by the statement in the title of this posting. There are many questions put into this because one must clarify all these subquestions in order to comprehensively answer the main question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open and shut case:

> "We were with the Prophet (ﷺ) [in a gathering] and he said: 'Pledge to me that you will not associate [anything as] partners with Allah, and that you will not steal nor commit adultery.' He recited to them the Ayah. (And he said:)'Whoever among you dies, then this reward is with Allah, and **whoever among you does some of this and then he is punished, it is atonement for him**. And whoever does some of this and Allah covers it for him, then it is up to Allah; if He wills, He will punish them, and if He wills, He will forgive him.'"

So, yes, they are forgiven for the specific sin they were punished for. But, I wouldn't say they would be granted Jannah automatically. They still have to answer for everything else.

Comment: Hmm... apostasy might be more nuanced.

Comment: @Rebecca . Yes, apostasy is different. I am just talking about crimes by muslims.

Comment: Apostasy by definition makes you a non-muslim. Plus the punishment of apostasy is for betrayal. Maybe that is forgiven and the person is punished like a normal disbeliever.