# Is using pirated software haram? if yes then what's the shari punishment for that?

Tags: fiqh, punishment, software, piracy

It's confusing me for decade that using pirated software is haram or not.

Can you please provide reference with your answer too?

Also, as per my understanding, every haram thing has a punishment, is it true? (with reference please).

And if yes, then what's the punishment in sharia for pirating a software?

Thanks.

Edit: this question is not duplicate of the other question as it asks for the "punishment" of the "haram" piracy (if its declared haram, with reference)

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your post and focus on the difference to the former proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is somewhat correct. Basically in the hereafter there we expect to be judged and if we have done wrong or if our wrongdoings have over weighted our good deeds we expect a punishment.

But punishments -in this life- according the shari'a are limited to certain crimes -and under certain conditions- ([apostasy](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/17/42), [murder](http://legacy.quran.com/4/93), adultery -for the [married](https://sunnah.com/muslim/28/34) and [unmarried](http://legacy.quran.com/24/2)-, [false accusation of adultery](http://legacy.quran.com/24/4), [robbery](http://legacy.quran.com/5/38), [hirabah](http://legacy.quran.com/5/33-34), [drinking alcohol](https://sunnah.com/muslim/29/60), etc. ) beside this we have [Qisas](http://legacy.quran.com/2/178-179) and the ruler or Qadi has the right to use [ta'azir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tazir).

Therefore a punishment for Software-piracy can only be decided case by case by a Qadi and may fall under ta'azir. Also note that if a person didn't repent in this life and was not condemned he/she should expect a punishment in the hereafter [Does punishment in the worldly life replace punishment in the hereafter?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40701/does-punishment-in-the-worldly-life-replace-punishment-in-the-hereafter/40704#40704).

See also
[What is the punishment for someone who pirates digital files?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4205/what-is-the-punishment-for-someone-who-pirates-digital-files) and
[Is using pirated software allowed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/600/is-using-pirated-software-allowed?noredirect=1&lq=1)